# decimal try parse in inline code

Tags: vb.net, inline-code

How to Decimal.TryParse in below line of code if value is null or empty then it should be 0 in inline coding in VB.NET

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ticket" id="ticket<%=y%>" title="<%=(CDec(Decimal.TryParse(late_fee)) + CDec(rs("ticket_amount")) + CDec(rs("nsf_fee")))-(CDec(rsp("TICKET_PAYMENTS")) + CDec(rsp("LATEFEE_PAYMENTS")) + CDec(rsp("NSFFEE_PAYMENTS")))%>" value="<%=rs("ticket_id")%>" checked="checked" onclick="doMath();"/>
```

Thanks for your advice

Comment: You cannot inline `TryParse` methods since you need to declare the variable first that will be returned from the `TryParse`-method. You either have to use multiple lines or create a method that returns it.

Comment: Can you please provide me any example that i can use  i update my question

Comment: With a big formula like this. I would put this code in a function instead or do it on the database side.

Answer (score 0):

TryParse returns true or false based on whether conversion was successful on not.

try:

```
double number;
Double.TryParse(late_fee, out number);
```

number: "When this method returns, contains the double-precision floating-point number equivalent of the late_fee parameter, if the conversion succeeded, or zero if the conversion failed"

Use the 'number'

```
 (CDec(number) + CDec(rs("ticket_amount")) + CDec(rs("nsf_fee")))-(CDec(rsp("TICKET_PAYMENTS")) + CDec(rsp("LATEFEE_PAYMENTS")) + CDec(rsp("NSFFEE_PAYMENTS")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot inline `TryParse` methods since you need to declare the variable first that will be returned from the `TryParse`-method. You either have to use multiple lines or create a method that returns it.

I would recommend to use variables anyway since that makes your code much more readable and that is the most important of all.

However, for what it's worth, you could make an extension which returns the decimal or a default value:

```
Module StringExtensions

    <Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Public Function ParseDecimal(ByVal aString As String, defValue As Decimal, Optional culture As Globalization.CultureInfo = Nothing) As Decimal
        Dim retVal As Decimal = defValue
        If culture Is Nothing Then culture = Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
        Decimal.TryParse(aString, Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, culture, retVal)
        Return retVal
    End Function

End Module
```

Then you could inline the calculation even if i would still use multiple lines and variables to increase readability.

```
Dim lateFee As Decimal = late_fee.ParseDecimal(0)  ' and the other variables ....
```